# Java Pattern Matching: Pattern.compile

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have an edit box. I am checking if the email address entered is valid or not.

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[\\w-]*@[\\.\\w-]*$");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("^\\w+$");
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(string);
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(string);    
return matcher1.matches();
return matcher2.matches();
```

Problem with this if my input my email address as spunker.baba@foo.com. matcher return false. It consider the char "." as invalid.

How should i modify my code such that it supports "." and matcher return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you've got two patterns (and two return statements!) instead of one... but your first pattern only includes `\w` and `-` before the @ sign, although it allows `.` afterwards. That's easy to modify, so that the first part is the same as the second part:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[\\.\\w-]*@[\\.\\w-]*$");
```

However, there are plenty of sites giving rather more exact email address matching regular expression patterns - for example [this one in Perl](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) (which I suspect will port simply enough to Java). There's also a page with a [fairly long explanation and Java code](http://leshazlewood.com/2006/02/04/java-email-address-validation-the-right-way-regular-expression/), if you want to also cope with addresses including friendly names. I'm sure if you search around you'll find a pattern which meets your exact needs - although quite how you judge which pages are reliable is another matter.

EDIT: If you want to be able to match without the last part, you can make it optional like this:

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("^[\\.\\w-]*(@[\\.\\w-]*)?$");
```

Comment: Your solution worked fixed my problem. But, now a second problem arised, if i dont enter "@" in the edit box, the matcher return false.

Comment: @SpunkerBaba: Why is that a problem? If there isn't an @ sign in the edit box, then it isn't a valid email address.

Comment: As per my requirement, if there isnt an @ sign, i have to add the my default domain name. User can enter the email-id without @, i will append @mydomain.com later in my code.

Comment: @SpunkerBaba: Frankly that would be easier to do without a regular expression. Do you absolutely *have* to do all of this using regular expressions? I'll edit the answer anyway...

Comment: Works like charm now. Thanks. I am open for suggestions, If you have an easier solution without regular expression, ill change my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\w-\.]*@[\\.\\w-]*$")
```

Note that this pattern will match non valid strings (assuming `@` isn't a valid email address). And it will also not match other valid email addresses (ie `name+other@gmail.com`)

Comment: Jave throws error                                                            Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: I forgot to escape the backslash. In Java, if you need to escape a character in a regex, you actually have to escape that backslash. I'll leave the error since this clears it up.